# Conjecture on limit of $1-(n^{p-1}\mod p)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Given $p \in \Bbb P$ prime, $n \in \Bbb N$ and

$$\mathcal V_p=1-(n^{p-1}\mod p)$$

let me *conjecture* that

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\mathcal V_p = \operatorname{sinc}(2\pi \,n)$$

***Question:*** *Is this conjecture true?*

Comment: Why not say the limit is just $0$?

Comment: Because of where I apply this theorem one example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436814/an-intuitive-interpretation-of-montgomery-pair-corrlation-function-vs-prime-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ does not divide $n$, we have $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, so $\mathcal V_p=0$ for almost all $p$.
And $\operatorname{sinc}(2\pi n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
So yes, your conjecture is true.

It is even true if you have $0\in\mathbb N$, for then we get $\mathcal V_p=1$ for all $p$ and $\operatorname{sinc}(0)=1$.

Comment: One question, why "almost" all $p$?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi As Hagen said, $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ holds, iff $p\mid n$. So the prime factors of $n$ are exceptions to this, but there are only finitely many, but infinitely many primes, so this justifies the term "almost all".