# Relation between $1-(n^{p-1}\mod p)$ and Riemann $\zeta$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

Taking:
$$\mathcal V_p=1-(n^{p-1}\mod p)$$
[with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436162/conjecture-on-limit-of-1-np-1-mod-p)
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\mathcal V_p = \operatorname{sinc}(2\pi \,n)$$
and Riemanns' well known [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Riemann_zeta_function), I get easily to this result:
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}[1-(n^{p-1}\mod p)] = \frac{\zeta(2n)}{\zeta(1-2n)}\left(\frac{1}{n\;(2\pi)^{2n}\;\Gamma(1-2n)}\right)$$

It is not spectacular, and I just beg your support, did I calculate something wrong, or is this true?

Comment: It seems to be correct.

Comment: Well, $\Gamma$ has poles in $1-2n$ for $n > 0$, $\zeta$ has zeros in $2n$ for $n < 0$, so $0 = 0$ holds. The only interesting cases would be $n = 0$.

Comment: Why is that an amazing result?

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to help to close the case.
seems the answer to my question is clear: the calculation is correct but the result is trivial.